# Antlr3: Could not match token in parser rules which is used in lexer rule

Tags: parsing, grammar, antlr3, lexer

I have lexer rules in Antlr3 as:

```
HYPHEN : '-';

TOKEN : HYPHEN CHARS;

CHARS : 'a' ..'z';
```

Parser rule is as:

```
exp : CHARS | some complex expression;
parser_rule : exp HYPHEN exp;
```

If I try to match 'abc-abc' with parser_rule, It fails. Because lexer creates TOKEN for HYPHEN exp. How can I match it correctly with parser_rule.

Answer (score 1):

In ANTLR lexer, the lexer rule that can match the longest sub-sequence of input is used. So your input

```
abc-abc
```

will be tokenized as

```
CHARS("abc")
TOKEN("-abc")
```

and therefore will not match the expected `CHARS HYPHEN CHARS`.

You should consider making `TOKEN` a parser rule instead of lexer rule.

Comment: I can not make HYPHAN CHARS a parser rule in my scenario. In my real case CHARS is not as simple as this. Please take a look of my other question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51359630/antlr3-grammar-does-not-match-rule-with-predicate
assume ID2 there as CHARS here. If I make it parser rule, then ID2 is not matched as ID1 is already matching it.

Comment: See my answer there, the answer is similar - you're probably trying to accomplish in lexer something that can only be done in parser.

Comment: Suppose I have modified token as parser rule. And consider above question in mind. I have a big parser rule as :
........... ID1 (other parser rule referring ID1).........(HYPHEN ID2) (this is now token) 

I don't want ID1 to match for underscore. And ID2 either can be 'abc_def' or normal 'abc'. Now when it is normal 'abc', parser would  fail as it is expecting ID2 but its tokenized as ID1. 

Even if it is 'abc_def' with flag = true  it will tokenize as ID1, UNDERSCORE, ID1, this will never match with ID2 .

Comment: How about you define `ID1` as just text, `ID2` as text with some underscores, and then `identifier1 : ID1` and `identifier2 : ID1 | ID2`? Would this be viable for your case?

Comment: Suppose ID1 can match some extra characters which are not valid in ID2 suppose @. In this case identifier2 will be matching that also. I don't want identifier2 to match that.

Comment: In such case you should probably have one token that matches the common ID syntax and separate tokens for the special IDs, then combine them in parser as you need.

Comment: Please take a look of the question posted here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51476284/can-not-provide-for-host-variables-in-antlr3-sql-grammar