# antlr4 lexer token invalid

Tags: antlr, antlr4, powerbuilder, antlr3

Trying to parse the below sentence, but the lexer generates incorrect token

**Input**

```
column(propName="~~" abc="hi")
```

**Lexer**

```
DOUBLEQUOTED: '"' (E_TILDE | ~ ('"') | E_DOUBLE_QUOTE)* '"';
fragment E_TILDE  : '~~'   ;
fragment E_DOUBLE_QUOTE   : '~"'   ;
```

**Trying to parse the input sentence, but the lexer generates the token**

```
'"~~" abc="' as double quoted string
```

**expected output**

```
'"~~"' as Double quoted string.
'"hi"' as Double quoted string
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Antlr3: Could not match token in parser rules which is used in lexer rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51378998/antlr3-could-not-match-token-in-parser-rules-which-is-used-in-lexer-rule)

Answer (score 1):

ANTLR Lexer matches the longest sub-sequence it can when determining the next token. Since `"~~" abc="` is a valid `DOUBLEQUOTED` token, and is longer than just `"~~"`, it will be matched.