# Can not provide for host variables in Antlr3 SQL grammar

Tags: java, sql, grammar, antlr3

I have a SQL grammar which do not have support for host variables. I want to provide support for host variables in that but a situation that I have encountered is tricky.

There is SQL Identifier lexer rule in grammar, which supports alphanumeric along with some special characters '@', '#', '$ and '_'.

Host variable's are dependent on language in which SQL is embedded. e.g. COBOL.
COBOL identifiers allow additionally hyphen(-) in variable names (Some other differences in them).

So I added LANG_ID additionally in grammar, which is matching COBOL identifiers.

Parser rule for host variable was like :

```
hostvariable : COLON WS* (ID | LANG_ID);
```

There was some other rule which was matching expressions. something like that:

```
expression :  identifier ('+' | '-')  identifier;
```

identifier here is parser rule which may have ID and some other tokens.

valid input for expressions is   ABC+ABC, ABC-ABC, ABC-12.

Now when input is like ABC-12, then it is getting tokenized as COBOL identifier.

Solution which I implemented was that, if its followed by COLON (:) , then only its COBOL identifier. Then I made LANG_ID fragment and created lexer rule as :

```
HOSTVAR : COLON WS* LANG_ID;
```

Now problem occurred with JSON_OBJECT SQL function which have syntax like:

JSON_OBJECT('KEY'  : VALUE)

There is a rule for JSON_OBJECT which expects something like
 **(character_literal COLON value_expression)**

value_expression could also be identifier.

In this case ': VALUE' is tokenized as HOSTVAR and JSON_OBJECT rule is failing.

I am not able to find any solution for the problem. In every approach something getting failed.

Comment: How do you determine whether `:ABC-12` is a COBOL identifier or `HOSTVAR` `MINUS` `NUMBER`? This is an issue with how you define your language, and you need to resolve it before trying to find a way to write a grammar for it. As for conflict with JSON_OBJECT, this is something that probably can't be resolved in lexer and needs to be deferred to parser, same as in https://stackoverflow.com/q/51378998/5375403.

Answer (score 0):

```
JSON_OBJECT('KEY' : VALUE)
```

syntax is not supported in IBM i COBOL. This can only be provided in the form of

```
JSON_OBJECT (KEY key VALUE value)
```

In the case of COBOL when COLON is followed by something, it should be treated as host variable.